# Doodle Jump like gameplay

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am pretty new to cocos2d.  Could someone please direct me to a good tutorial on how to make a game like doodle jump.  I need to know how to make him bounce of the platforms, spawn platforms, use the accelerometer to control the player, etc.

Thanks

Comment: This is far too broad of a question.  We're not going to walk you through how to write a Doodle Jump knockoff, but we would be glad to answer specific questions that you have about challenges in developing something like this.

Comment: I wasn't asking you too, I'm simply new to cocos2D and need some guidence on where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check TweeJump: http://github.com/haqu/tweejump

It has the doodle jump basic functionality. You'll have to update it to the latest cocos2d version, but it is a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The primary developer of Cocos2d offers the source to a complete sample game for purchase here: [Sapus Tongue Source](http://www.sapusmedia.com/sources/).